# Using XMLHttpRequest to delete a file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to delete a file in my JS script.

I have tried to use a XMLHttpRequest to open a php-file that deletes the file but unfortunately it doesn't work. I was hoping someone could point me towards whats going wrong:

JS:

```
function rmbusyfile(filename){
  var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr2.open('POST', 'rmbusyfile.php');
  xhr2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr2.send("file="+encodeURIComponent(filename));
  console.log("file=" + filename);
}
```

rmbusyfile.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["file"])){
  unlink($_POST["file"]);
}else{
//print_r($_POST);
echo "Error";
http_response_code(400);
}
?>
```

Comment: The `Content-Type` header conflicts with the data format you actually send (probably not the actual issue here). Also, you're exposing your server to an attack, it's more than easy to send what ever path to your script, which then removes it without any checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses the Content-Type header to determine how to (and if it can) parse the request body.

You are claiming to send JSON, which:

- PHP does not support for automatic parsing into `$_POST`
- doesn't match the data you are sending.

Consequently, PHP doesn't try to parse the body and `$_POST` is left empty.

---

Don't lie in the Content-Type header. Tell PHP what data format you are really sending.

```
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

---

Note that you are letting users pass any path they like. This gives them the ability to delete any file on the server for which the user PHP is running as has write access. You should add some verification to the input to check such things as "Does this file really exist?", "Is this file in the server of files that this PHP program should have control over?" and "Do I trust this particular user to delete this file?"